# Pandas Trial Repetioin indexing

Tags: indexing, dataframe, pandas

I have a data set where pictures were presented 3 times and measurements were taken for each presentation. Prospectively I would like to normalize the values for each picture (based on the 3 repetitions - so 3 numbers) and run an ANOVA on the categories: first presentation, second presentation, third presentation (for all pictures). Before I get to that, however, I have to reorganize my data so that I can easily access data - based on the picture name AND the number of the repetition.

I would like to convert a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
viola.jpg          0.61  1.968234      1
vlasta.jpg         0.79  1.836025      2
zelmira.jpg        0.76  1.955471      3
viola.jpg          0.71  1.968234      4
vlasta.jpg         0.89  1.836025      5
zelmira.jpg        0.76  1.955471      6
viola.jpg          0.31  1.968234      7
vlasta.jpg         0.79  1.836025      8
zelmira.jpg        0.26  1.955471      9
```

To one which looks like this:

```
viola.jpg   1   0.61    1.968234        1
            2   0.71    1.968234        4
            3   0.31    1.968234        7
vlasta.jpg  1   0.79    1.836025        2
            2   0.89    1.836025        5
            3   0.79    1.836025        8
zelmira.jpg 1   0.76    1.955471        3
            2   0.76    1.955471        6
            3   0.26    1.955471        9
```

I have tried using df.groupby(), df.pivot, and df.stack() in various combinations, but apparently they don't even vaguely do something like what I am looking for - any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a DataFrame `df`, you can set your `image name` and `measurement id` fields as an index then sort.  That will order the data how you want.

```
df2 = df.set_index("pic_name", "meas_id").sort()
```

`groupby` and `pivot` are good for performing aggregations over groups of data or when you have something specific you need to do to individual groups.  `stack` and `unstack` help with reshaping your data, but move indexes to cols and vice versa.

Comment: wow - that is awesome and simple, thank you :) Could you also tell me how I can get the 1-3 numbering (I will need this to select my categories for the ANOVA)

Comment: @TheChymera, Do you have exactly 3 measurements for every image?

Comment: You could try something like, `meas_id = [1,2,3] * (len(df2.index) / 3)` and then do `df3 = df2.reset_index().set_index(["pic_name", meas_id])`.  I think that should work as long as there are no missing measurements.